# What test can I use to calculate significance of optimization lift?

Tags: excel, statistics, hypothesis-test, statistical-test

Given the following data for 12 users:
username, number of deals for control, revenue from test, revenue from control

Here's an example of how the data looks like
[image]

Can you help me figure out how I can calculate the significance of the hypothesis that the test is more profitable (preferably using excel)?
The measure I was thinking of using was the % of lift in revenues for each customer.

P.s. I have a background in statistics but not an expert so please keep it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Since each pair of incomes refers to the same individual, you can perform a paired t-test.

Variable 1: Control income

Variable 2: Deals income

Then follow [these instructions](https://statisticsbyjim.com/hypothesis-testing/t-tests-excel/) (copied here for posterity):

> - In Excel, click Data Analysis on the Data tab.
> - From the Data Analysis popup, choose t-Test: Paired Two Sample for Means.
> - Under Input, select the ranges for both Variable 1 and Variable 2.
> - In Hypothesized Mean Difference, you’ll typically enter zero. This value is the null hypothesis value, which represents no effect. In
>   this case, a mean difference of zero represents no difference between
>   the two methods, which is no effect.
> - Check the Labels checkbox if you have meaningful variables labels in row 1. This option helps make the output easier to interpret. Ensure
>   that you include the label row in step #3.
> - Excel uses a default Alpha value of 0.05, which is usually a good value. Alpha is the significance level. Change this value only when
>   you have a specific reason for doing so.
> - Click OK.

Alternatively, you can indeed calculate the difference between the two incomes, and then perform a one sample t-test (assuming that the difference is zero). However, such a test is not available out-of-the-box in Excel; the procedure is [described here](https://www.real-statistics.com/students-t-distribution/one-sample-t-test/).